# Find all matrices satisfying $X^3=I-X$

Tags: linear-algebra

We are studying for a qualifying exam and have come across the following problem in a previous exam.

> Determine the solutions (if any) of the matrix equation $X^3=I-X$ in the $2 \times 2$-matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

Any hints in the right direction would be much appreciate for this.

Comment: Start from the diagonal case.Then you will identify necessary conditions for eigenvalues. After this it is easy to prove that if $X$ is solution then  $VXV^{-1}$ for any non singular $V$ is also a solution.Actually you even don't have to diagonalize. If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue and $u$ is eigenvector than you have $\lambda^3=1-\lambda$ . Solve the equation. All matrices with such eigenvalues will be solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3+x-1$ has one real root $\alpha$ and two conjugate complex non real roots $\beta$ and $\overline \beta$. Since this polynomial annihilates the matrix $X$ then their eigenvalues belong to the set of roots of the polynomial and since $X$ is a real matrix then there's two cases:

- $\alpha$ is the only eigenvalue of $X$ and if $X$ isn't diagonalizable then the minimal polynomial is $(x-\alpha)^2$ divides the given polynomial which isn't true so $X$ is diagonalizable and then $X$ is similar to $\alpha I_2$.
- $\beta$ and $\overline\beta$ are the eigenvalues of $X$ so the minimal polynomial of $X$ is $(x-\beta)(x-\overline\beta)=x^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\beta) x+|\beta|^2$ so let
  $$X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
  and since
  $$\chi_X(x)=\det(X-xI_2)=(a-x)(d-x)-cb=x^2-(a+d)x+ad-cb$$
  hence we choose $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that
  $$a+d=2\operatorname{Re}(\beta)\quad;\quad ad-cb=|\beta|^2$$

Comment: Being similar to $\alpha I$ means being equal to $\alpha I$.

Comment: Absolutely right:-)

Comment: Also, possibly worth noting that $|\beta|^2 = \beta\bar\beta = \alpha^{-1}$, and $\beta+\bar\beta=2\mathrm{Re}(\beta)=-\alpha$.

Comment: Why would $\beta$ be related to $\alpha$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The matrix satisfies $X^3+X-I=0$. What can you say about the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 3):

The equation is $x^3+x-1=0$ now a two by two matrix has a minimal polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. So which quadratic or linear polynomials divide tbe above cubic ?

Comment: Notice that, if there is a quadratic polynomial that divides $x^3+x-1$ then there must be also a linear polynomial that divides it (the quotient). Hence, it suffices to check whether or not there is a linear polynomial that divides the matrix.

Comment: @bartgol Well it has just one real root. So see the accepted answer, it is not really clear what the best from to express the matrices with quadratic minimal poly. I would like to know what the intended answer was, since it is for a qualifying exam.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can start looking at the eigenvalues of $X$. What kind of relationship there is? Can you find the eigenvalues of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that this polynomial has one real root and two complex conjugates.  For a real matrix, if one of the complex solutions is an eigenvalue then so is the other.  A real $2 \times 2$ matrix with eigenvalues $a \pm bi$ is 
$$ \pmatrix{ s & t \cr -((a-s)^2 + b^2)/t & 2a - s }$$
for arbitrary $s$ and $t \ne 0$.

On the other hand, if the real root $r$ is an eigenvalue, it is the only one, and
has geometric multiplicity $2$, so the matrix is $r I$.